# Scraping from a website that requires a login?

Tags: php

Can this be done if so, how? I want to scrape data from xbox.com but the pages I need to scrape only appear after a successful login.

Comment: Either find a way to execute the login handshake or **don't scrape sites you haven't asked permission about**.

Comment: @Josh K: he's asking how to execute the login handshake, not bypass it.

Comment: Josh is absolutely correct about this. However, I don't agree with the person who downvoted this, if it was for this reason. It's a legitimate technical question.

Comment: @Patrick The site may disallow whatever use he intends to make of the data by scraping it, even if they allow him to log in and browse the site as a human user. The fact that he's scraping rather than using an API provided by the site tends to support this view. But innocent until proven guilty, of course.

Comment: I believe it was unwarranted legal advise, which SO is not for. For all we know the OP could be scraping his personal gaming statistics. And whatever else he is scraping might fall under fair use terms if it's for personal or academic purposes. Just because it's a .com site doesn't mean it doesn't host user contributed content either.

Comment: @Patrick: He's not asking that, he has a vague question with a solitary `[php]` tag. He has provided the absolute minimum amount of verbiage required to have a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to go through the required login transaction by sending POST data with your CURL requests.  That said, it is a bad idea to scrape data from behind a login - the site didn't put that information in the public for a reason, and for you to do so might constitute copyright infringement,

Answer (score 9):

Most login forms will set a cookie. So you should use a HTTP class like Zend_Http that can store them for further requests. It's presumably as simple as:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setCookieJar();   // this is the crucial part for "logging in"

// make login request
$client->setUri("http://xbox.com/login");
$client->setParameterPost("login", "hackz0r");
$result = $client->request('POST');

// go scraping
...
```

Comment: This answer is the best it actually answers the OP question instead of being pretentious and telling him that its not a good idea to scrape behind a login. There are lots of legitimate reasons to do this for example pulling data from old corporate tools that your company refuses to get rid of

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in theory, provided you have a web fetching class that supports cookies. It looks like PHP [`HTTP_Request2`](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) from PEAR can send cookies if you provide the cookie information as part of the request. All you should need to do would be:

- Send a login request
- Extract the cookie data from the HTTP headers of the response to the above request
- Set this cookie data on subsequent requests

Note that many sites will have anti-scraping techniques of varying degrees of sophistication, and may make this more difficult. It may also be illegal, immoral or contrary to the site user agreement.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to login automatically, some more complicated than others. xbox.com probably uses the Windows Live API, so you'll have to look into the documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP library [PGBrowser](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/pgbrowser) can get this done pretty easily. Below is a demo code snippet taken from the [companion blog](http://scraperblog.blogspot.ca/2012/12/scraping-site-that-requires-login-in.html). I believe this won't work with the XBox website because Microsoft now uses SSO, but is still applicable to other websites with content behind login forms.

```
require 'pgbrowser.php';

$b = new PGBrowser();
$b->useCache = true;

$page = $b->get('http://yoursite.com/login'); // Retrieve login web page
$form = $page->forms(1); // Retrieve form

// Note the form field names have to be specified
$form->set('username', "your_username_or_email");
$form->set('password', "your_password");
$page = $form->submit(); // Submit form

echo $page->html; // This shows the web page normally displayed after successful login, e.g. dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//initial request with login data

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/list');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```