# How can I crawl a page for data as if it's logged in if I have the login credentials?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I need to scrape some data from a page that doesn't belong to my domain. I know how to load up the page server side and parse it in various different languages (asp.net, PHP etc) however, I need to scrape the page after it's been logged in.

For example the page would have an HTML tag with an attribute set to the user ID like so:

```
<div id="profile" data-userid="1234"></div>
```

The data-userid attribute wouldn't have an ID in it unless logged in. Is it possible to login to a site on the server side? (I do have login credentials)

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Yes, you can use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to do this.  Just create a cURL session, configure it to use cookies, emulate the login through an HTTP request, and then access the pages you want to see logged in.  There should be plenty of examples on SO if you search around.

Comment: so tired of seeing this exact question over and over. if it requires a log in, they probably don't want you scraping their data. if they did, they would have an api.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scraping from a website that requires a login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997147/scraping-from-a-website-that-requires-a-login)

Comment: @dqhendricks it is very similar to the question you posted. My mistake, I should have looked better. However, now that I see that question some people bring up legalities... Do you know if its illegal to scrape data from your own profile that you can go get yourself by logging in?

Comment: @tsdexter you will have to read the terms of service agreement for the service you are using. chance are, you should not be doing this.

Comment: @dqhendricks I've searched the terms of service and found no references to scrape or crawl - as well, I'm not taking their data and redisplaying it for sale. I'm just getting the users ID# as well, I'm not collecting or storing any data as the users will install the script on their own server and only scrape their own profiles... What do you think? (ps. I appreciate your advice)

Comment: There is nothing inherently illegal or wrong with scraping web sites that require a login.  The technology used to implement a site has nothing to do with the legality of the process.  If you have any doubt that what you're doing might get you in trouble, simple send a note off to the owners of the site indicating what you plan to do and how you plan to use the data.  If they have objections, they'll let you know.

Comment: Whether something is legal or not depends for the most part on where you are located, and where the server is located. For example since I am in the UK, and my server is also, it is pretty plain I am covered by UK law. In general I'd say scraping was fine, but re-displaying it could breach copyright or confidentiality. Since a website in most cases is private property, the owner is free to take technical measures against scraping (such as suspending an account used to grant access to the scraper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to use an HTTP component in your crawler that is session-aware; you logon programmatically, and with each crawl supply the cookie that you get from your logon action. Test suites often have such a components - see for example [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Read about [curl](http://php.net/curl) and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` in particular.  You can use curl to post forms and maintain a session cookie.