# grab a variable value from external webpage for processing?

Tags: php, html, variables, post, get

Let me just start by saying I know almost nothing about PHP but, I think that may prove to be the best way to do what I'm trying to do. I'd like to grab the value of a variable from an external page so that I can then process it for the creation of graphs and statistics on my page. An example page that I'm trying to get the variable from (requires a Facebook Account) is - http://superherocity.klicknation.com/game/pages/battle_replay.php?battle=857337182

The variable name is fvars and it contains data about what the 2 players used for attacks, how much damage they did, etc. Ultimately what I'd like is to provide a page with a form where a player can go and plug in their replay link (like above) and get a nice neat detailed breakdown of the battle.

At the very least, if someone could explain to me how to just echo out the value of fvars after a form submission with the replay url as input it would help out immensely!!! I've tried looking at some PHP references and other posts here but, have so far been lost.  :(

Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: Just the below which I figured wouldn't work  

    `<?php 
 $file = file_get_contents('http://superherocity.klicknation.com/game/pages/battle_replay.php?battle=857337182'); 
 Echo $fvars;
 ?>`

Comment: Unfortunately that would simply get the contents of that page, without any of the auth cookies needed. Not sure if the cookies would work, but you may be able to experiment with the bash wget comment. It allows you to pass cookies. Then you'd need to actually parse the page. The variable won't get automagically set with either file_get_contents OR wget.

Comment: How is this page working - http://www.shc-strategy.com/ ? It's doing exactly what I'm trying to do.  :(

Answer (score 2):

One way you could approach it is to use Selenium. You would need to setup the selenium server and a browser and then write a selenium script to fetch the page for you. The key point here is that selenium can run a firefox client with javascripts, facebook logins etc, everything you have on your ordinary firefox, through selenium programmatically.

I run selenium in a Linux environment and control it through php cli scripts. I run the java selenium-server-standalone along with framebuffered X and firefox. PHP Unit test library allready has an extension though you wouldn't need it for testing obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of any webpage like so:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

And then just use regex or basic searching to find the variable you need in $homepage.  The problem is that you need to be logged in via Facebook.  I know of no current way to do this dynamically with PHP.
Mike

Edit: found an SO question that addresses this exact issue - [Scraping from a website that requires a login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997147/scraping-from-a-website-that-requires-a-login)

Comment: The login piece is not needed as the only ones using the page will be logged in already. So if I use the above command to read in the entire contents of the page to the variable $homepage can I then reference the variables contained in that page directly? For example if I followed your command above with an echo fvars would it output the value of fvars?

Comment: It wouldn't matter if the user is logged in on their local browser as a client.  The PHP code is running on the back end on your web server.  That PHP code is what needs to get logged in to retrieve the variable.  In the link I provided above, some people gave some options.  Or you try Oli's idea, which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Another player has already crafted a similar page to what I'm trying to do - http://www.shc-strategy.com/ - where a player can plug in the replay link. As long as you have a Facebook account and a game account (it uses Facebook Connect) then you can access the replay URLs. The other player has not chosen to share his page with everyone all the time. I would like to make a similar resource available all the time to everyone regardless of whether or not you're on his good side.