# Permanent access to youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using YoutubeAPI v3.0 to automatically upload videos to my own channel. However the script still needs manual intervention during Oath2.0 authorization. How to make it completely automatic?

1) Access the API using username and password

2) Or find a way to create permanent OAuth2.0 authentication

P/S: I use this script to upload

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Comment: What do you mean by manual intervention? If the user has to enter some data, couldn't your script just automatically provide the information needed to authenticate whenever necessary?

Comment: Theoretically Yes. But in terms of implementation, this is the manual step which I have problems overcoming https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/OauthUX_nocallback.png

Comment: Isn't that the point of OAuth, though, to enforce that manual step? That way, nothing can be uploaded without explicit permission of the account holder. I don't think Youtube _wants_ videos automatically uploaded, for a variety of reasons (some that protect you as a user, some that protect them).

Comment: But that user is ME, and I really don't want to do that every once and then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube oAuth 2.0 API permanent code to retreive tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006335/youtube-oauth-2-0-api-permanent-code-to-retreive-tokens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is web scraping. Basically, programmatically open the web page and get its HTML. Then find the authorization code, and store it as a string. I don't know if your scripting language of choice can do it, but Python has Beautiful Soup (links at the bottom). The problem, of course, is accessing the contents of a page like that which is pretty clearly designed to be reached by a logged in user from a web browser. I've never done that, but there's some concept of a "login handshake" where you post the data to the server that's needed as you access the page. I've a few links at the bottom.

Anyway, to give you a better idea of what I mean in pseudo-code (for those who may be confused), it'd be something like:

```
webURL = 'http://any-url.net";
webPageObject = openPage(webURL);
pageHTML = webPageObject.getHTML();
theHTMLTag = searchForTagById(pageHTML, "<p id='oAuthMessage'>");
//And from there, figure out where the string containing the code is.
//Probably just by getting a substring from the end of the text in the <p>
//backward until you reach the length of the oAuth code.
```

You'll have to look at the page source to know which tags to look for specifically, but this can all just be done programmatically/automatically, as you wanted.

Links:

Login handshake - [Scraping from a website that requires a login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997147/scraping-from-a-website-that-requires-a-login)

Beautiful Soup - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

google.gov/webScraping - https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=how+to+web+scrape+logged+in+page

Answer (score 0):

You can use get Google OAUTH2 for devices in order to have fully automatic token renewal process.

So all you need now is:

1. Request a `device code` and `confirmation code`
2. Enter `confirmation code` to confirm your application have access for specific account
3. Generate new or renew existing `ACCESS_TOKEN` for your `device code`
4. Upload Video using your `device code` and valid `ACCESS_TOKEN`

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/devices) is documentation for it.

And [here](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/samples/oauth2_for_devices.py) is some examples.