# How to redirect to another page after Google Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, google-signin

I am using google login as my SSO but when i successfully login with Google it redirect me back to my login page how can i redirect it to my homepage after login using Google login?

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
            GoogleProfile profile = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleProfile>(json);
            Label1.Text = profile.Id;
            Label2.Text = profile.DisplayName.ToString();
            Label3.Text = profile.Emails.Find(email => email.Type == "account").Value;


            Image1.ImageUrl = profile.Image.Url;
            ImageButton1.Visible = false;
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
        }
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleConnect.Authorize("profile", "email");

    }
```

Comment: don't you get the token in the query string, you can validate it and later redirect it to the home page

Comment: i only got the refresh token. How do i get the access token?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41860759/713789

Comment: which part of it shows the part of retrieving the access token? Sorry

Comment: I don't have the code but I do the same thing 2 weeks ago, send the token and get the access token (which is expire in 3600 seconds = 1 hour)

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a callback url in google authentication api. After callback the provided url will called and method defined is this will be executed. In that method you will get user information and token to validate. After that you can redirect to your home page.

Answer (score 1):

google callback give you success or error message. if you got success flag you get an array with user data. with those data you need to set an session. so you wont go back to your login page. or else when you call google api you haven't set proper call back for your application.